# how to create time array

Tags: java

I have an arraylist arr which contains a series of number, like 07, 52, 25, 10, 19, 55, 15, 18, 41. In this list first item is hour, second is minute and third is second, like 07:52:25.
Now I want to create a time array in which i can insert these values and do some arithmetic operation like difference between first index and second index, which gives me the time difference. So how can i do that?

```
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ":Mode set - Out of Service In Service");
while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
    arr.add(st.nextToken());
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you do not want to parse it into Date or Calendar object and then operate on it? That would let you make any time calculations without any extra hassle.

Comment: Why don't you store `Date` or `Calendar`  values in the array?

Comment: This is the fourth question you post with the same code attached to it...

Comment: @Giann: yes I know. Actually I was trying to solve the problem with different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i think i understand what you want your code to do. Heres how i would do it.

```
public class DateHandler
{
    public DateHandler(int seconds, int minutes, int hours)
    {
        this.seconds = seconds;
        this.minutes = minutes;
        this.hours = hours;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "Seconds: "+seconds+" Minutes: "+minutes+" Hours: "+hours;
    }

    public int seconds;
    public int minutes;
    public int hours;
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int[] data = {07, 52, 25, 10, 19, 55, 15, 18, 41}
        int numberOfDates = data.length/3//Divide by 3 because there are 3 numbers per date
        ArrayList<DateHandler> dates = new ArrayList<DateHandler>(numberOfDates);
        for(int x=0;x<numberOfDates;x++)
        {
            int index = x*3;
            DateHandler date = new DateHandler(data[index],data[index+1],data[index+2]);
            System.out.println("added date: "+date.toString());
            dates.add(date);
        }

        //here you can do your calculations.
    }
}
```

I hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

I would use split to tokenise. You can read any amount of times from multi-line data

```
BufferedReader br = 
String line;
List<Integer> times = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] timesArr = line.split(", ?");

    for(int i=0;i<timesArr.length-2;i+=3)
        times.add(Integer.parseInt(times[i]) * 3600 +
              Integer.parseInt(times[i+1]) * 60 + 
              Integer.parseInt(times[i+2]));
}
br.close();

System.out.println(times); // prints three times in seconds.
// difference between times
for(int i=0;i<times.size()-1;i++)
   System.out.println("Between "+i+" and "+(i+1)+
       " was "+(times.get(i+1)-times.get(i))+" seconds.");
```

Comment: Thanks peter. but this data(time) is just an example. I have a lot of data(I mean variable length array). I want to split that in hours, min and sec.

Comment: Split works on any length of string. If you have multiple lines of data you can read these in a loop and add them to the `times` as well.

Comment: @ricky, I have changed the example to take input from a reader which can be a file, socket or console.

Comment: thanks man. 80% of my problem is solved. I will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

If this array (you said "arraylist arr" right?)

```
07, 52, 25, 10, 19, 55, 15, 18, 41
```

means

```
7:52:25, 10:19:55 and 15:18:41
```

Then you can use [SimpleDateformat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to "convert" a string to a date.

[SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) can [parse](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29) ("convert") a `String` to a `Date`, and to [format](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date,%20java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.text.FieldPosition%29) a `Date` to a `String` (actually a `StringBuffer`).

In your case, you loop through your `ArrayList` group the hours, minutes and seconds, and use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse them:

```
    int index = 0;
    String tempTime = "";
    ArrayList<Date> dateList = new ArrayList<Date>();

    //assuming hour in format 0-23, if 1-24 use k in place of h
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h-m-s-"); 

    for(String timeeElement : timeArrayList)
    {
       tempTime +=  timeeElement;
       tempTime += "-"; //To handle situations when there is only one digit.
       index++;
       if(index % 3 == 0)
       {
          Date d = dateFormat.parse(tempTime, new ParsePosition(0));
          dateList.add(d);
          tempTime = "";
       } 

    }
```

You have a list of dates to play with now